# Coffeescript & ejs how to add html every x items from array

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, ejs, compoundjs

Im using nodeJs.. I have the following javascript.. to iterate over an array of projects from my database. i was doing this server side, that way the data was pre sorted and when using handlebars all i had to do was a simple nested each statement..

This was from when i was using geddy..

```
function transform ( arr ) {
   var result = [], temp = [];
   arr.forEach( function ( elem, i ) {
   if ( i > 0 && i % 3 === 0 ) {
   result.push( temp );
   temp = [];
   }
   temp.push( elem );
   });
   if ( temp.length > 0 ) {
   result.push( temp );
   }
   return result;
}
```

I have translated the above js to coffeescript..

```
temp = []
result = []
for row, i in projects
  if i > 0 && i % 3 is 0
    result.push(temp)
    temp = []
  temp.push(projects)
if temp.length > 0
  result.push(temp)
```

that being said i have the following coffeescript ajax request:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $.ajax '/projects.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (x,h,r) ->
    projects = x.data
    ## iterate through all of the projects
```

I am trying to insert some additional HTML after the third iteration to accomplish the following:

[image]

The html that makes up the above screenshot is this, its bootstrap 2.3:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">    
      <li class="span4 thumb-hover">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="/img/projects/" class="" target="_blank"><img src="/img/projects/thumbnails/admirecleaningservice_thumbnail.png" width="300px" height="200px"></a>
          <div class="mask">
            <h4>Admire Cleaning Services</h4>
            <p>Test 123</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="span4 thumb-hover">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="/img/projects/" class="" target="_blank"><img src="/img/projects/thumbnails/admirecleaningservice_thumbnail.png" width="300px" height="200px"></a>
          <div class="mask">
            <h4>Admire Cleaning Services</h4>
            <p>Test 123</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="span4 thumb-hover">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="/img/projects/" class="" target="_blank"><img src="/img/projects/thumbnails/admirecleaningservice_thumbnail.png" width="300px" height="200px"></a>
          <div class="mask">
            <h4>Admire Cleaning Services</h4>
            <p>Test 123</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="thumbnails">    
      <li class="span4 thumb-hover">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="/img/projects/" class="" target="_blank"><img src="/img/projects/thumbnails/admirecleaningservice_thumbnail.png" width="300px" height="200px"></a>
          <div class="mask">
            <h4>Admire Cleaning Services</h4>
            <p>Test 123</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="span4 thumb-hover">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="/img/projects/" class="" target="_blank"><img src="/img/projects/thumbnails/admirecleaningservice_thumbnail.png" width="300px" height="200px"></a>
          <div class="mask">
            <h4>Admire Cleaning Services</h4>
            <p>Test 123</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="span4 thumb-hover">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="/img/projects/" class="" target="_blank"><img src="/img/projects/thumbnails/admirecleaningservice_thumbnail.png" width="300px" height="200px"></a>
          <div class="mask">
            <h4>Admire Cleaning Services</h4>
            <p>Test 123</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Would it be more beneficial to organize the array controller side, pass to the render method and then have ejs just do two nested loops, use jquery and an ajax request to inject or some other method?

Comment: Have you tried a cycle function ?

Comment: NFI what that is, so probably not :)

Comment: i figured out how to convert the js to coffee script for the organizing of the array properly. But it just seems like duplicate work..